# Lost Code Signing Certificate Alias

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, keystore, thawte

Our company purchased a code signing certificate from Thawte a few weeks ago.  When we finally received the certificate from the purchasing team they didn't know the alias for the certificate!

I don't seem to be able to import the cert without the alias and they have no clue at all what it is.  Is there a way of retrieving the alias?  Has anybody else run into this problem?  Is there any way of importing without the alias?

Comment: What is the keystore format - JKS or otherwise? And what tools are you using - keytool, openssl or any other?

Comment: Sounds like somebody in your team needs to be fired :-)

Answer (score 4):

The alias is specified during the creation of the private key of the RSA certificate. It is not decided by the certificate signing authority, rather by the person creating the private and public keys.

I can't speak on whether your purchasing department ought to know this, but you'll need to check with the person/department who generated the CSR to determine the toolkit used to generate the CSR, and the key store format.

Now, assuming that the Java keytool utility was utilized to create the CSR, and that the private key is managed in a JKS keystore, you can utilize the keytool command to determine the contents (and hence the alias) of the keystore. This can be done using the `keytool -list` as indicated in the other answer. A sample run is demonstrated below, with the alias appearing in the output:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore foo.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: foo
Creation date: Sep 1, 2010
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=foo, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=foo
Issuer: CN=foo, OU=foo, O=foo, L=foo, ST=foo, C=foo
```

Note that you do not need to know the keystore password to read the contents of the keystore, in which case a warning will be displayed.

In case you are using another toolkit and/or keystore format, you'll need to adopt a similar approach to determine the contents of the keystore, for the alias is not bound to appear in the CSR.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
keytool -list -keystore certificate.jks
```

(Note that if your keystore isn't JKS, for example, PKCS12, you can add an optional -storetype option to change the keystore type:)

```
keytool -list -keystore certificate.p12 -storetype PKCS12
```

You'll have something like:

> Keystore type: JKS
>   Keystore provider: SUN
>
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
>
> mykey, Feb 1, 2010, trustedCertEntry,
>   Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 0F:73:59:5C:35:8C:F2:F0:27:7E:F7:B7:AF:0A:95:B4

Your certificate alias is shown on the first line of the certificate description, here 'mykey'.